# Even using asyncio and aiohttp, methods wait for the request response

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Hi I have the following issue, I want to execute getlastItemFromGivenInterval method, let it briefly to go through without waiting for request reponses, and give a context to asyncio.sleep(60) to execute the whole procedure once more in 60 seconds time frames. What I get is waiting in getLastItemFromGivenInterval() for request end.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            await bc.getLastItemFromGivenInterval(session)
            await asyncio.sleep(60)

async def getLastItemFromGivenInterval(session):
    async with session.get(BinanceClient.base_endpoint + "/api/v1/time") as currentServerTime:
        currentServerTime = await currentServerTime.json()
        currentServerTime = currentServerTime['serverTime']

    async with session.get(url) as res:
        response = await res.json()
        array = []
        print(response)

        return response
```

getLastItemFromGivenInterval is placed in the separate class.
Please give me a hint how to achieve not waiting effect in getLastItem...() method.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your question, but it seems that your problem is that the `getlastItemFromGivenInterval` and `sleep` are synchronous -- If you want to run them concurrently, then you probably want to await the result of an `asyncio.gather` -- `await asyncio.gather(bc.getLastItemFromGivenInterval(session), asyncio.sleep(60))` rather than awaiting each item individually.

Comment: @mgilson I think the OP doesn't want to wait for `getLastItemFromGivenInterval` at all. `gather()` will parallelize the sleep with the coroutine execution, but it can still take arbitrarily long to complete if the coroutine ends up taking a long time, and that's something the OP is working to avoid.

Comment: How to get the result of the first coroutine in the asyncio.gather() just after it is finished?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to start `getLastItemFromGivenInterval` in the background, and do so every 60 seconds regardless of how long it takes to complete. You can replace `await` with `create_task`, and then never awaiting the resulting task:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
    # spawn the task in the background, and proceed
    loop.create_task(bc.getLastItemFromGivenInterval(session))
    # wait 60 seconds, allowing the above task (and other
    # tasks managed by the event loop) to run
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

You might want to also ensure that tasks that take a long time to complete or that hang indefinitely (e.g. due to a network failure) don't accumulate:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
    # asyncio.wait_for will cancel the task if it takes longer
    # than the specified duration
    loop.create_task(asyncio.wait_for(
        bc.getLastItemFromGivenInterval(session), 500))
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```